# How to retrieve category of a post in have_post loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, categories

I am using a CPT (post_type => 'portfolio_type', taxonomy => 'portfolio_cat'). Under this CPT, I have design, web development category. I am trying to get the post with the category. My best try,

```
function callback_for_portfolio_shortcode(){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $parent_cat
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
            $cat_str = '';

            //loop through the category and get a string of category
            foreach($post_categories as $c){
                $cat = get_category( $c );
                $cat_str .= $cat->name;
            }
            $html .= '<h4>'.$query->post->post_title.'</h4>'; //works fine 
            $html .= '<h4>'.substr(get_field('job_description', $id), 0, 100).'</h4>'; //works fine 
            $html .= '<h4>'.post_permalink().'</h4>'; //works fine 
            $html .= '<h4>'.$cat_str.'</h4>'; //does not work    
        endwhile;
    endif;
    return $html;
}
```

$cat_str is empty. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: You use the wrong operator to concatenate strings, you should replace it with `.=`.    `$cat_str .= $cat->name;`

Comment: just a typo mistake. sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_get_post_categories()` and `get_category()` are specifically for the `category` taxonomy. You're using a custom taxonomy, `portfolio_cat`, so you need to use [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) to get categories.

```
$categories = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'portfolio_cat' );
$cat_str    = '';

foreach ( $post_categories as $category ) {
    $cat_str .= $category->name;
}
```

If you just want a comma separated list of category links, you can use [`get_the_term_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/) to simplify the code:

```
$cat_str = get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'portfolio_cat', '', ', ', '' );
```

Or, if you don't want links, you can do this instead:

```
$categories = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'portfolio_cat' );
$cat_str    = implode( ', ', wp_list_pluck( $categories, 'name' ) );
```

Also, instead of `$query->post->post_title` you should really just be using `get_the_title();`.

Comment: Thanks! I should read documentation more carefully! Really appreciate your detail answer!